# Does Google Bigtable has support for stored procedures?

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

Is there support for stored procedures in Google Bigtable, or support for any similar mechanism for saving multi-statement queries?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: Bigtable is a NOSQL key-value database.
An option with support to create stored procedures on Google Cloud is CloudSQL.

Comment: Thanks, @Eumagnun, I will check that.